# Lucee on Windows BIN folder relocation

Tags: windows, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to get Lucee Express running on windows for several of my sites.  I am also running ACF for most of my sites so I manually setup each site I want to use Lucee.  This works fine for most sites except one.

The issue I have with the one site is that the code in that site conflicts with the BIN folder lucee/boncode uses.

So my question is, is there a way to have lucee/boncode to reference a different folder (like _BIN or BIN_Lucee) so that I do not get this conflict?